# Cannot invoke code on the main thread from the background thread in iOS6

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios6, nsmanagedobjectcontext

When saving a managed object context on a background thread I am listening to the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and trying to merge it on the main thread.

However when I try to forward the request to the main thread, none of the code is executed neither using

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(executeThisCode:) withObject:saveNotification waitUntilDone:NO];
```

nor with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    ...execute this code
});
```

Strangely, it all works fine with iOS 5.1 and iOS 5.0, but not with iOS 6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you first check whether you are already in the main thread? This would be expecially relevant if `executeThisCode` is the selector for the method you are currently executing when calling `performSelectorOnMainThread`. Something like this:

```
- (void) executeThisCode: (NSNotification*) notification{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(executeThisCode:) 
                                 withObject:notification 
                              waitUntilDone:YES];
       return;
    }

    // merge logic goes here and executes on the main thread
}
```

Comment: Could you try with waitUntilDone: YES? I noticed you have that set to NO.